# Count number of entries in another dataframe given a certain condition

Tags: r, dataframe, count, plyr, tidyr

I have the following problem: I have two dataframes. `df1` contains among other variables (which are not shown in the code below) a date-variable. In `df2` I have an id (refering to the id in table `df1`), a factor-variable (type) and another date.

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=1:5, referenceDate=c("2018-01-20","2018-02-03","2018-05-20", "2018-08-01", "2018-07-31"))
df2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,4,4,5,5), type=c("A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B"), dates=c("2018-01-10", "2018-01-23", "2018-01-24", "2018-05-21", "2018-05-18", "2018-06-01", "2018-09-01", "2018-07-10", "2018-07-20"))
```

My goal is to create a new column in `df1` indicating the number of rows in `df2` where (e.g.) `df2$type`=='A' and `df2$dates` occures before `df1$referenceDate`.

In R I have the following solution that gives me the number of rows where `df2$type`=='A'. But how can I additionally consider the date? I had the idea of first joining the two tables in order to get the `referenceDate`-Variable from `df1` into `df2` and then do the counting and join the two tables again in the other direction (in order to get the count variable back into `df1`). But this does not sound very elegant to me.

```
library(tidyverse)
reduced <- df2 %>% filter(type=='A') %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(count=n()) %>% filter(!duplicated(id))
df1 %>% left_join(reduced[, c("id", "count")])
```

Comment: `dplyr` doesn't allow for joins on anything but equality, but `data.table` will let you do "non-equi joins", on a condition like `df2.dates < df1.referenceDate`. In `dplyr` the equivalent is to join without a date condition and then filter.

Comment: you can use the sqldf package to join on a less than
`sqldf("Select df1.id, df1.referenceDate, count(df2.id) as NumberCasers
      from df1
      left join df2 on df1.id= df2.id 
        and df2.dates < df1.referenceDate 
        and df2.type='A'
      group by df1.id, df1.referenceDate")`

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you want:

```
df1 <- tibble(id = 1:5, 
              referenceDate = as.Date(c("2018-01-20","2018-02-03","2018-05-20", "2018-08-01", "2018-07-31")))

df2 <- tibble(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,4,4,5,5), 
              type = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B"), 
              dates = as.Date(c("2018-01-10", "2018-01-23", "2018-01-24", "2018-05-21", "2018-05-18", "2018-06-01", "2018-09-01", "2018-07-10", "2018-07-20")))


df1 %>% 
  left_join(
    df2 %>% 
      left_join(df1, by = 'id') %>% 
      filter(dates < referenceDate) %>% 
      group_by(id) %>% 
      count(type) %>% 
      ungroup(),
    by = 'id'
  )
```

The key is  to join `df1` to `df2` *first* and then filter based on reference date. That allows you to use `filter` to keep what you want.  Then, use `count`. *Then* join back to `df1`